# Angular route is not getting resolved in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, route-provider

While working on my angular app I have an issue that a route which is easily resolved in Google Chrome can not be resolved in mozilla.
Every time I click on a link  it redirects me to the default ('/') route URL.

Here is my code snippet for that code :-

```
.when('/profile/add/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/add-profile.html',
    controller: 'AddProfileCtrl'
})
```

below is the HTML code

```
<a href="#/profile/add/ " class="btn-floating " title="Add a profile ">
      <i class="fa fa-plus "></i>
    </a>
```

Although I am able to route the URL easliy through URL address bar but not through any link href in mozilla fireox.

Comment: Can you post the html for your href?

Comment: <a href="#/profile/add/ " class="btn-floating " title="Add a profile ">
      <i class="fa fa-plus "></i>
    </a>

Comment: does that work in other browsers ? I.e or safari

Comment: have you used any hasbang url something like $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!') ? If yes then you will have to change the url in anchor tag to "#!/profile"

Comment: No , Have not used any hashbang URL

Comment: Working in safari and opera

Answer (score 1):

```
 Example:
   app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){ 
     $stateProvider
        .state("home",{
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: './view/home.php',   
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        });     
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home'); });
```

You can try with `$stateProvider` and `$urlRouterProvider`....